# Ajax request returns 404 not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, opencart

I have been trying to find a solution for this but I dont seem to find one. I get a 404 response when I try to perform the following ajax call. The code works fine on localhost but when I upload the changes on the remoter server, I get the error

```
$('#button-upload').on('click', function() {
    $('#form-upload').remove();

    $('body').prepend('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-upload" style="display: none;"><input type="file" name="file" value="" /></form>');

    $('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').trigger('click');

    if (typeof timer != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').val() != '') {
            clearInterval(timer);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/upload&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&directory=<?php echo $directory; ?>',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: new FormData($('#form-upload')[0]),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#button-upload i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');
                    $('#button-upload').prop('disabled', true);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#button-upload i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-upload"></i>');
                    $('#button-upload').prop('disabled', false);
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    if (json['error']) {
                        alert(json['error']);
                    }

                    if (json['success']) {
                        alert(json['success']);

                        $('#button-refresh').trigger('click');
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

The console error is

```
POST https://example.com/admin/index.php?  route=common/filemanager/upload&token=jyHPuiTt1DjdemKjNWUbeZqOtHHj4Dxw 404 (Not Found)
```

Several attempts while debugging has made my hosting provider block my IP address for security reasons. How does making the ajax request appear as a threat and do the security measures taken by my hosting provider could have caused the error? I can actually access the URL from the web address of my browser but not from the ajax call

Comment: What error you are getting .?

Comment: but the file on the server is also named `index.php` or there is a file named like `index.php`? can you post the wohle `alerted` error message?

Comment: @Dileep Chris The error is exactly as above

Comment: Is `index.php` in the `/admin/` directory? You may want to review the structure of the request being made (i.e. `https://example.com/admin/index.php?`).

Comment: You might have to put the name of the folder that resides on the server that holds your project in the beginning of your `url`.. so maybe something like: `"/FolderName/...`

Comment: @War10ck Yes..it is

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
url: '/index.php?route=common/filemanager/upload&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&directory=<?php echo $directory; ?>',
```